# JFileChooserDialog shows filetype filter when set to directory only

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

#### Problem statement

A directory chooser dialog is prepared. No files are allowed to be chosen, only directories. In order to do so, the `JFileChooser` is prepared:

```
private void prepareFileManagement()
    {
        // unrelated code
        ...
        
        // export filters
        this.exportFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY );
        this.exportFileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed( false );
    }
```

Dialog filters work as intended so far. However when displaying the dialog, there is still a "Files of type" label and the corresponding combobox shown:

[image: Filetype objects still shown in directory chooser dialog]

#### Question

It does not seem to make sense to display the filetype section, when `JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY` is set. Is there an API available to the `JFileChooser` to update the displayed dialog accordingly?

While I have found solutions, where components are iterated and identified using a barrage of `instanceof`, this seems like something that should be done by an API and not by tearing the `Component` apart.

Is there an API for the `JFileChooser` I have missed? How to solve this correctly?

#### Meta

I have looked for similiar questions on **StackOverflow**, the closest one in my opinion is this:

[Java - Remove component (Files of Type) from JFileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314512/java-remove-component-files-of-type-from-jfilechooser)